# Why no HashMap data structure in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm currently creating a model where I want to call some "put" methods on a HashMap. The order of the keys does not matter here, so I figured that a HashMap was the best fit for the problem.

However, I can only see the "LinkedHashMap" option in the properties of the "collection" block. Is there a particular way of making the "collection" become a HashMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Java data structure you like, the drop-down is just a suggestion.

However, it is easier to just define a variable in such a case:
[image]